# How to disable some of time value selection in html input tag type="time"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an `input` as `type="time"` when user click to select a time, I would like to disable some of time stamps for example 8:30 and 10:30 be disabled and user be not able to choose them. Preferably with JavaScript or css if possible.

**Any idea how to do it?**

[image]

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="appt">Select a time:</label>
  <input type="time" id="appt" name="appt">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Edited:**

After getting a suggestion with this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time)
I decided to use `<dataList>` as below, when I disable the option they disappear from list what is unsuitable for my cass.

**Any suggestion why it disappear instead of disabling?**

```
<input type="time" id="appt" name="appt" list="time-list">

   <datalist id="time-list" >
        <option id="08" name="08"  value="08:30" datatype="time" disabled>
        <option id="09" name="09" value="09:30" datatype="time" >
        <option id="10" name="10" value="10:30" datatype="time">
        <option id="11" name="11" value="11:30" datatype="time" disabled>
        <option id="13" name="13" value="13:30" datatype="time" >
        <option id="20" name="20" value="20:30" datatype="time">
    </datalist>
```

Comment: Please only add tags that are relevant to the question at hand. This has nothing to do with any server side language (like PHP or Java)

Comment: That’s not possible natively: you will need to implement your own time selection UI to have specifically disable time slots.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time there is your API, if you don't find your desired functionality you need to make your own component for it or use some 3rd party library. Patern property might be what you want.

Comment: the reason why I put java and php is that may someone has already created such a functionality to dynamically create or manipulate a html and push it to client side for example Vaadin does such a things